# Finding primes in python3

Tags: python-3.x, primes

The code:

```
def prime(n):
from math import sqrt
for i in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1): 
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
return True
```

will correctly find primes, but I don't understand why it returns 2 as a prime when:

```
print(2%2)
```

prints 0, can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

`int(sqrt(2)) + 1` is `2`, and `range(2, 2)` is empty (the upper bound is exclusive), so the body of the loop never runs.